# Need to free EVP_MD* from EVP_sha256()?

Tags: openssl

I'm using OpenSSL and not really familiar with it. Trying to use it to decode something someone is sending me from another programming language in a data package. Anyways, the info is encoded with OpenSSL and so I need to decode it using it. I have it working more or less, but I am concerned about resource usage.

I am using `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()` to make a digest_key following the way it was encrypted. One of the arguments to the function requires calling `EVP_sha256()`. When using functions like this, usually I am used to calling another function to free the memory or handle. I cannot find a function that is appropriate for freeing the handle/pointer returned. I am calling from C++ if that makes any difference.

Should I just always call `EVP_sha256()` before a call to `PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC()`, or should I use a static variable in C++ so that it only gets called once? Do I have to worry about running out of memory by repeatedly calling it, or is it always returning a pointer to something that only gets allocated once?

... 10 minutes elapse...

Ok, I just looked at the source code. It's returning a pointer to something that is statically allocated already, so it appears I don't need to worry about clearing it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to free the return from `EVP_sha256()` or from any other similar function which returns a "const" pointer to an `EVP_MD`, `EVP_CIPHER` etc. In the forthcoming OpenSSL 3.0 there are functions that return non-const pointers (`EVP_MD_fetch()`, `EVP_CIPHER_fetch()` etc). If you're using OpenSSL 3.0, and start using those functions then you will have to free them.